# Android HttpUrlConnection EOFException on internet

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I'm creating an android app that connect to my pc using connectify and do an http get request and work fine but when i tried with my server in internet with a copy of my local rest api doesn't work help me please thanks in advance this is my code

```
public static String makeRequest(RequestPackage p) throws Exception {

        BufferedReader reader = null;
        int status =0;
        String uri = p.getUri();
        if(p.getMethod().equals("GET")){
            uri += "?" + p.getEncondedParams();
        }

        URL url = new URL(uri);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod(p.getMethod());

        if (p.getMethod().equals("POST")){
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());

            writer.write(p.getEncondedParams());
            writer.flush();
            status = con.getResponseCode();
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        con.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        con.setReadTimeout(30000);
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

        String line;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            sb.append(line+"\n");
        }
        con.disconnect();

        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Comment: `with a copy of my local rest api`. You could elaborate on that as there are so many possibilities.

Comment: `con.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        con.setReadTimeout(30000);` You should put those statements befor the write's.

Comment: `doesn't work `. What exactly does not work? Do we have to guess? Errors? Exceptions? What is the content in `sb.toString()` ?

Comment: i get EOFException in this line reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream())); i think that is cause of i'm executing a get request and the url is something long but locally all is fine,  besides
when i paste the url in navigator works too,then if i generate a shortest url i don't get this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can check response code. If it's not 200 (OK), getInputStream perhaps returns null, then use getErrorStream. Hope this help since I met the same issue yesterday.

```
            urlConnection.connect();
            int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            } else {
                inputStream = urlConnection.getErrorStream();
            }
```